# Converting gausian function into SSE

Tags: sse, simd

Hi i am working on Gaussian blur. I am using below function to calculate pixel value after applying 1 D Gaussian kernel on it. I want to convert this function to very efficient SSE so that i can get significant perf improvement but i have never worked on it so could not write a proper one. can some one please help me with this.

```
struct PixelValue   
{
    uint32_t R;  // 32bpp so that we don't overflow on below add
    uint32 G;  
    uint32 B;
    uint32 A;
};

Pixel FindPixelvalue(short* gausianFilter, short filterSize, unsigned int* pixels)
{
    Pixel out;
    const char* srcByte = reinterpret_cast< const char * >( pixels );

    while ( filterSize > 0 )
    {
       short value = *gausianFilter;

       out.R = out.R + *srcByte++ * value;
       out.G = out.G + *srcByte++ * value;
       out.B = out.B + *srcByte++ * value;
       out.A = out.A + *srcByte++ * value;

       gausianFilter++;
       filterSize--;
   }

   return out;
}
```

Comment: Intel has a tutorial / case-study on [doing a Gaussian blur with AVX](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/iir-gaussian-blur-filter-implementation-using-intel-advanced-vector-extensions).  They use floating-point for the coefficients / math.  If you just need a one-dimensional filter, leave out the part where the horizontal pass transposes its output to set up for the vertical pass.  I also found [a post on codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32630/sse-intrinsics-gaussian-blur-approximation)

Comment: I also found a [discussion in an issue on github for libass (a subtitle rendering library)](https://github.com/libass/libass/issues/9).  Anyway, so 16bit integer gaussian coefficients is enough precision?

Comment: Thanks Peter i will try this. I am not sure about gaussian coefficients precision i am kinda new on this so i keep trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the biggest speedup, you probably need to calculate multiple pixels at once.  Trying to get a SIMD speedup for a single pixel at a time would take more shuffling along the way.

I'm going to assume your pixel color components are `uint8_t`, even though you actually cast them to `char`.  (`char` can be signed or unsigned.  IDK which it is in the Linux or Windows 64bit ABI, because you're doing something wrong if it ever matters.)

---

Here's a first attempt at how the data-movement could go.  I think it's sub-optimal, with too much shuffling.  Intel's [AVX case-study](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/iir-gaussian-blur-filter-implementation-using-intel-advanced-vector-extensions) computes results for multiple rows in parallel, so they can *broadcast* a single gaussian coefficient before a multiply, instead of needing to shuffle multiple coefficients into a pattern.

- load 8 gaussian coefficients (one 16B vector of 8 words)
- load 8 consecutive pixels (two 16B vectors of 4 pix each): `{R1 G1 B1 A1 R2 G2 B2 A2 ...}`, `{R5 G5 B5 A5 ...}`
- interleave the low halves (`punpcklbw`) so you have `{R1 R5 G1 G5 B1 B5 A1 A5   R2 R6 ... }`.  (Later, repeat this with the high halves)
- unpack with zero (`punpcklbw` / `punpckhbw`) into two vectors of word elements
- shuffle the gaussian coefficients into `{C1 C5 C1 C5 C1 C5 ...}`
- `pmaddwd` between the coefficients and the pixel data.  It multiplies vertically and then adds horizontal pairs into 32bit elements.  This is the motivation for the earlier interleaving, and arranging the gaussian coefficients to match.
- repeat for the other three groups of pixels, with `{C2 C6 C2 C6 ...}` coefficients
- add the results to an accumulator (`paddd`).

At the end, you'll have a vector with four elements: `{R G B A}`.

See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) wiki page for links to guides (like Intel's intrinsics guide to help you find the C intrinsic for the instruction you want).

Like I said, this is probably not optimal.  `pmaddwd` is a really nice multiple-and-add with 16bit inputs and 32bit outputs, but shuffling the data so elements that can be added together are horizontally adjacent is probably more overhead than just using the slower `pmulld` (SSE4.1 normal 32bit packed multiply).  That would make it possible to work on multiple pixels at once, and broadcast a word at a time of the coefficient array.  (AVX2 `vpbroadcastw`, or two-step shuffling.)

Comment: Thanks Peter i was able to do it using some of Intel AVX + they way you desribed. Thanku so much